# Entity Framework 5 CF Firebird - Same Code creates different queries

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, firebird, firebird2.5

I got a huge problem with the SQL generation in my REST-Service:

The following Code is generating 2 different SQL-Statements (PC Win8 vs Server 2008 R2):

```
    private void GetData()
    {
        ctPostBox = new CTPostBox(GetDBConnection(DatabaseKind.dkGlobal));

        var lQry = (from d in ctPostBox.CONTACTUSER.Include("CONTACT").Include("CONTACT.DBLINK").Include("CONTACT.CONTACTLASTUSED").Include("CONTACT.EMAILACCOUNT")
                     where ((d.CONTACT.ID_DBLINK == 0 || d.CONTACT.ID_DBLINK == null) || (d.CONTACT.DBLINK.MANDNR == UserConfig.mandNr))
                     select new
                     {
                         READDATE = d.READDATE,
                         ID = d.CONTACT.ID,
                         DBID = d.CONTACT.DBID,
                         DATEINSERT = d.CONTACT.DATEINSERT,
                         FROMUSER = d.CONTACT.FROMUSER,
                         FILENAME = d.CONTACT.FILENAME,
                         KIND = d.CONTACT.KIND,
                         MSGID = d.CONTACT.MSGID,
                         ID_DBLINK = d.CONTACT.ID_DBLINK,
                         DBID_DBLINK = d.CONTACT.DBID_DBLINK,
                         SUBJECT = d.CONTACT.SUBJECT,
                         STATE = d.CONTACT.STATE,
                         DATEINCOME = d.CONTACT.DATEINCOME,
                         DATESEND = d.CONTACT.DATESEND,
                         ID_EMAILACCOUNT = d.CONTACT.ID_EMAILACCOUNT,
                         DBID_EMAILACCOUNT = d.CONTACT.DBID_EMAILACCOUNT,    
                         GESCHST = d.CONTACT.DBLINK.GESCHST,
                         d.CONTACT.DBLINK.KEYTYP,
                         KONTO = d.CONTACT.EMAILACCOUNT.NAME
                     });

        WriteFile(@"C:\Temp\log.log",lQry.ToString());
    }
```

SQL Development PC (everything is fine):

```
    SELECT 
    "C"."ID_CONTACT" AS "ID_CONTACT", 
    "C"."READDATE" AS "READDATE", 
    "C"."DBID_CONTACT" AS "DBID_CONTACT", 
    "D"."DATEINSERT" AS "DATEINSERT", 
    "D"."FROMUSER" AS "FROMUSER", 
    "D"."FILENAME" AS "FILENAME", 
    "D"."KIND" AS "KIND", 
    "D"."MSGID" AS "MSGID", 
    "D"."ID_DBLINK" AS "ID_DBLINK", 
    "D"."DBID_DBLINK" AS "DBID_DBLINK", 
    "D"."SUBJECT" AS "SUBJECT", 
    "D"."STATE" AS "STATE", 
    "D"."DATEINCOME" AS "DATEINCOME", 
    "D"."DATESEND" AS "DATESEND", 
    "D"."ID_EMAILACCOUNT" AS "ID_EMAILACCOUNT", 
    "D"."DBID_EMAILACCOUNT" AS "DBID_EMAILACCOUNT", 
    "F"."GESCHST" AS "GESCHST", 
    "F"."KEYTYP" AS "KEYTYP", 
    "H"."NAME" AS "NAME"
    FROM    "CONTACTUSER" AS "C"
    INNER JOIN "CONTACT" AS "D" ON ("C"."ID_CONTACT" = "D"."ID") AND ("C"."DBID_CONTACT" = "D"."DBID")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "DBLINK" AS "F" ON ("D"."ID_DBLINK" = "F"."ID") AND ("D"."DBID_DBLINK" = "F"."DBID")
    INNER JOIN "EMAILACCOUNT" AS "H" ON ("D"."ID_EMAILACCOUNT" = "H"."ID") AND ("D"."DBID_EMAILACCOUNT" = "H"."DBID")
    WHERE ((0 = "D"."ID_DBLINK") OR ("D"."ID_DBLINK" IS NULL)) OR ("F"."MANDNR" =         @p__linq__0)
```

SQL Server (multible JOINS on DBLINK, very slow):

```
    SELECT 
    "C"."ID_CONTACT" AS "ID_CONTACT", 
    "C"."READDATE" AS "READDATE", 
    "C"."DBID_CONTACT" AS "DBID_CONTACT", 
    "F"."DATEINSERT" AS "DATEINSERT", 
    "F"."FROMUSER" AS "FROMUSER", 
    "F"."FILENAME" AS "FILENAME", 
    "F"."KIND" AS "KIND", 
    "F"."MSGID" AS "MSGID", 
    "F"."ID_DBLINK" AS "ID_DBLINK", 
    "F"."DBID_DBLINK" AS "DBID_DBLINK", 
    "F"."SUBJECT" AS "SUBJECT", 
    "F"."STATE" AS "STATE", 
    "F"."DATEINCOME" AS "DATEINCOME", 
    "F"."DATESEND" AS "DATESEND", 
    "F"."ID_EMAILACCOUNT" AS "ID_EMAILACCOUNT", 
    "F"."DBID_EMAILACCOUNT" AS "DBID_EMAILACCOUNT", 
    "J"."GESCHST" AS "GESCHST", 
    "L"."KEYTYP" AS "KEYTYP", 
    "N"."NAME" AS "NAME"
    FROM       "CONTACTUSER" AS "C"
    INNER JOIN "CONTACT" AS "D" ON ("C"."DBID_CONTACT" = "D"."DBID") AND     ("C"."ID_CONTACT" = "D"."ID")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "CONTACT" AS "F" ON ("C"."DBID_CONTACT" = "F"."DBID") AND ("C"."ID_CONTACT" = "F"."ID")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "DBLINK" AS "H" ON ("F"."DBID_DBLINK" = "H"."DBID") AND ("F"."ID_DBLINK" = "H"."ID")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "DBLINK" AS "J" ON ("F"."DBID_DBLINK" = "J"."DBID") AND ("F"."ID_DBLINK" = "J"."ID")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "DBLINK" AS "L" ON ("F"."DBID_DBLINK" = "L"."DBID") AND ("F"."ID_DBLINK" = "L"."ID")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "EMAILACCOUNT" AS "N" ON ("F"."DBID_EMAILACCOUNT" = "N"."DBID")         AND ("F"."ID_EMAILACCOUNT" = "N"."ID")
    WHERE ((0 = "D"."ID_DBLINK") OR ("F"."ID_DBLINK" IS NULL)) OR ("H"."MANDNR" = @p__linq__0)
```

And here the code first data:
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CONTACT>()
            .HasOptional(b => b.DBLINK)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.ID_DBLINK, b.DBID_DBLINK });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CONTACT>()
        .HasKey(d => new { d.ID, d.DBID })
        .HasMany(d => d.CONTACTUSER)
        .WithRequired(d => d.CONTACT)
        .HasForeignKey(l => new { l.ID_CONTACT, l.DBID_CONTACT });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CONTACT>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.EMAILACCOUNT)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.ID_EMAILACCOUNT, b.DBID_EMAILACCOUNT });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CONTACT>().HasKey(a => new { a.ID, a.DBID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<DBLINK>().HasKey(a => new { a.ID, a.DBID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<CONTACTUSER>().HasKey(a => new { a.ID, a.DBID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<EMAILACCOUNT>().HasKey(a => new { a.ID, a.DBID });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I'm searching for days now. How can the same code generate different SQL-Statements?

1. IIS Version (Development PC: IIS 8, Server IIS7.5)
2. Both environments are using the same Database-Server (Firebird 2.5)
3. I copied the whole project to the server, no changes...
4. The Projekt is set to .NET 4.5
5. I created a sample WPF-Projekt with this function and it resulted using the RIGHT SQL on the server
6. FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll Version 3.0.2.0 EntityFramework.dll 5.0.0

Do you have any idea what can infuence the query creation this way?

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not able to reproduce the "bug". Everything works fine on my (2) Development machines. Only Hosted in the IIS on my Server the problem seems to occur.

Comment: Check what assemblies are *really* loaded. I bet the EF's assemblies differ (because it's EF who generates the structure of query).

Comment: Nope the loaded Dlls are the same: EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0; FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=3.0.2.0

Comment: via: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();